# What can I do with old computer?

Tags: server

I have old computer with Intel Celeron 1.6Ghz dual-core processor, 3 GB RAM. What can I do with this computer so that it will be helpful?

Comment: In what part is this programming question? I'm sorry, but this question is off topic on this site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is nothing to do directly with programming or programming tools

Answer (score 0):

Web server? Media server? Crowd Computing? Linux machine for learning purposes? Game server? It isn't bad config after all. The only problem might be power consumption.